# SpecFlow Comparing two identical sets fails

Tags: c#, specflow

My problem statement: I have data defined in a test table and also data coming from an API and parsed into struct.

I have a test table that is as follows in Gherkin and also defined in code as:

```
| Name      | Values    |
| Start     | foo,bar   |
| End       | bar,foo   |
| Status    | foo-bar   |

Public Class SessionFilterTable {
    public string? Name {get; set;}
    public string[]? Values {get; set;}
}
```

My test step is as follows:

`table.CompareToSet<DataItem>(apiResp);`

For some reason the comparison is failing every time. The exception information does not seem to show me what is wrong. The expected and actual look the same.

Are there some gotchas with SpecFlow table / set comparison?

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the SpecFlow data table, the `DataItem` class and the `SessionFilterTable` class. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full step definition, including all relevant step definitions for any `Given` or `When` steps that precede it.